# Wait for a Button to load Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code:

```
'What do i put here to wait until V that down there exists before continuing?

ie.Document.getElementById(":zv.gt").Click

'Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 5000: Loop <---- Wont work because the button doesnt actually popup until after the Page is already finished loading.
```

What do i put to have it continually check to see if the button exists before going on?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the trick. Thx Anyways StackOverflow.

```
 'Waits for button to load and clicks the button once loaded
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Do  
        On Error Resume Next
        set x = ie.Document.getElementById(":zv.Ss")
        If x is nothing then
           wscript.sleep 200
        else    
            ie.Document.getElementById(":zv.Ss").click
        Exit Do
        end if
        On Error Goto 0   
    Loop
```